# How to use the "touch" command to create a .py file?

Tags: cmd

When I try using the touch command I get an error saying:'touch' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The touch command in only available on **Unix** based OS.

However, you can do the same on Windows by running:

`type nul > your_file.py`

Answer (score 0):

dont't use `touch` command for `windows`

use `echo` command with redirect operation use > to overwrite and >> to append

```
c:\Windows\path>echo "" > file.py
```

Comment: Well, this creates a file containing two quotation marks, a space and a line-break…